# Java equivalent c# implicit

Tags: java, android

I have an object A

```
class A {
    B contained = new B();
}

class B
{
}
```

and a collection of A's

```
Queue<A> q1 = new PriorityQueue<A>();
```

what I want to do

```
Queue<B> q2 = new PriorityQueue<B>(q1);
```

in c# I can use the implicit keyword, is there an equivalent?

Comment: I don't see how you could do this with `implicit` in C#. `Queue<A>` is an interface (so it can't have overloaded operators) and you can't change the code, because it is part of the standard libraries.

Comment: A would have an implicit conversion to B, not the Queue itself

Comment: that wouldn't work, because generics do not lift operators. There would be no conversion between Queue<A> and Queue<B>, even if there was a conversion between A and B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you need to have

```
Queue<B> q2 = new PriorityQueue<B>();
for(A a: q1) q2.add(a.contained);
```

I can't image you would want to do this very often. Is this a very useful feature?

Comment: Applying a projection to a collection? That's a very useful feature that is used very often. In C# you don't do it with the implicit keyword, though, but with LINQ's `select` operator. It would be something like `Queue<B> q2 = new PriorityQueue<B>(from a in q1 select a.contained);`.

Comment: Java tends to provide minimal features.  Very often a simple loop is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you use `PriorityQueue` in Java, then the classes needs to implement comparable interface. Next thing to do, is to think what kind of equality contract do you want between `A` and `B`. Keyword `implicit` in C# seems to be a simple cast transform.

I imagine equivalent in Java would look like:

```
    Queue<A> q1 = new PriorityQueue<A>(Arrays.asList(new A(), new A(), new A()));
    Queue<B> q2 = new PriorityQueue<B>(Collections2.transform(q1, A.toB));
```

Class A would probably look like:

```
static class A implements Comparable<A> {
    B contained = new B();

    public static final Function<A, B> toB = new Function<A, B>() {
        @Override public B apply(A a) {
            return a.contained;
        }
    };

    @Override public int compareTo(A a) {
        return contained.compareTo(a.contained);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 but I cannot use this because it is not in Android, I screwed up on the tags so someone removed it but I added the tag back.